# Changing global variable from within a function?

Tags: python, function, variables, global

Just for practice, I'm trying to recreate the game [Dudo](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dudo) within Python (I don't think knowledge of the game affects my question that much though). Basically, six players have a certain number of dice (represented by count1, count2 etc.), and I need to know the number of each kind of die (How many 1s, how many 2s etc.). I created a variable num1 (num1 = 0) to represent the number of 1s, and then I made a function to find the number of 1s.

```
def find_num1():
    total = 0
    for i in range(you_count):
        if you[i] == 1:
            total = total + 1
    for i in range(count1):
        if enemy1[i] == 1:
            total = total + 1
    for i in range(count2):
        if enemy2[i] == 1:
            total = total + 1
    for i in range(count3):
        if enemy3[i] == 1:
            total = total + 1
    for i in range(count4):
        if enemy4[i] == 1:
            total = total + 1
    for i in range(count5):
        if enemy5[i] == 1:
            total = total + 1
    num1 = total
    print total
```

Each player has a list of six numbers that represents each die they have (enemy1, enemy2 etc.). So I used a loop to go through each list index to find the number 1 and then update a total based on that. When I run the function, it correctly prints total. However, if I tell it to print num1 (outside of the function) it tells me 0, meaning that my function did not correctly change num1 to total. Does anyone have any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks!

Comment: Write `global num1` as the first line of the function (Python 2) or `nonlocal num1` (Python 3).

Comment: Thanks! I'm using Python 3 but for some reason it works with global instead of nonlocal... any reason why?

Comment: `global` works in both versions. The `nonlocal` statement is Python 3 only and it means something different. It's used to modify variables in a non-global outer scope, which only comes up when you define functions within other functions.

Answer (score 1):

Tell the program `num1` is a global variable

```
def find_num1():
    global num1 #Here
    total = 0
    for i in range(you_count):
        if you[i] == 1:
            total = total + 1
    for i in range(count1):
        if enemy1[i] == 1:
            total = total + 1
    for i in range(count2):
        if enemy2[i] == 1:
            total = total + 1
    for i in range(count3):
        if enemy3[i] == 1:
            total = total + 1
    for i in range(count4):
        if enemy4[i] == 1:
            total = total + 1
    for i in range(count5):
        if enemy5[i] == 1:
            total = total + 1
    num1 = total
    print total
```

Comment: This one works! Thanks! 
Just wondering though, I'm fresh from CodeAcademy and this was never a problem before. Is there are a reason functions are made like this? Does this mean I can re-use the names of variables as long as they're in different functions?

Comment: Python has good documentation on [scoping](https://docs.python.org/3.4/reference/executionmodel.html).

Answer (score 1):

As your programs get longer, having too many global variables will make your program hard to understand, hard to fix when you find bugs, and hard to improve when you want to add features.  Fortunately, there's a clean way to pass a value from a function back to the main program: `return`.  If your top level does `foo = some_func()`, and `some_func()` ends with `return 5`, then 5 will be assigned to `foo` after `some_func()` finishes.  You could rewrite as follows:

```
def find_num1():
    total = 0
    for i in range(you_count):
        if you[i] == 1:
            total = total + 1
    for i in range(count1):
        if enemy1[i] == 1:
            total = total + 1
    for i in range(count2):
        if enemy2[i] == 1:
            total = total + 1
    for i in range(count3):
        if enemy3[i] == 1:
            total = total + 1
    for i in range(count4):
        if enemy4[i] == 1:
            total = total + 1
    for i in range(count5):
        if enemy5[i] == 1:
            total = total + 1
    return total

num1 = find_num1()
print(num1)
```

You can even return multiple values by creating a tuple out of them in the function and unpacking the tuple at top level:

```
def sum_and_product(a, b):
    sum_value = a + b
    prod_value = a * b
    return (sum_value, prod_value)

(plusle, times) = sum_and_product(3, 5)
# the function returned (8, 15), and after unpacking,
# plusle is now 8 and times is now 15
```

See also [`return` examples](http://learnpythonthehardway.org/book/ex21.html) from *Learn Python the Hard Way*.

<sub>Code in this answer is dual licensed: [CC BY-SA 3.0](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/) or the [MIT License as published by OSI](http://opensource.org/licenses/MIT).</sub>

Comment: This is what I was going to write. One small improvement: the parentheses around the values being `return`ed, and on the left side of the assignment are not necessary. You only need to use parentheses to create a tuple if it would be ambiguous otherwise (e.g. in a function call). You only need them on the left side of an assignment if you're unpacking a nested structure (e.g. `(a,b), c = [["foo", "bar"], "quux"]`).